# OpenCV project on iPhone - opencv.hpp building issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, opencv

I've cloned https://github.com/niw/iphone_opencv_test and tried to replace

```
#import <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h>
#import <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
```

with

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

in `OpenCVTestViewController.m` file. But XCode threw following error:

```
iphone_opencv_test/opencv_device/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp:55:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp' file not found [2]
 #include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
```

So, I've tried to remove the line `#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"` from the `opencv.hpp` file. The error below was thrown:

```
iphone_opencv_test/opencv_device/include/opencv2/ml/ml.hpp:2075:10: fatal error: 'map' file not found [2]
 #include <map>
```

I've also tried to change .m to .mm, but it seemed futile. Where I'm wrong?

Comment: you can try this framework... http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

Comment: @Aravindhanarvi thank you for reply. I'm already using this project's approach, but I just want to know __why__ the project's (I've posted) approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a conflict between OpenCV's MAX/MIN macros and Cocoa's MAX/MIN. It leads to strange errors like this one at compile time. To bypass this problem, you can either:
1. add  at the top of the pre-defined header file
2. totally decouple opencv and obj-c code, so that no .m/.mm file includes . This can be done for example by using boost GIL in-between, or using custom vanilla C++ classes to pass image data from Cocoa frameworks to opencv C++ image processing classes.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I wanted!

Comment: do you have any tutorial of how to use boost GIL?

Comment: This one is tricky, I think you should ask the question on StackOverflow. Short answer: you don't need it if you just pass out pointers to the data fields, and if you add the line #import <opencv2/opencv.hpp> before the #import <cocoa...> in the .pch file.